# fail2ban regex pattern for apache logs

Tags: regex, linux, iptables

Having trouble getting a regex pattern to work with fail2ban.  Our server was getting hit with sqlmap penetration testing and I wanted to be able to ban the IPs when these are logged.    From other examples I've seen, it appears I don't have to try and match each section of the log entries but can just search for a word or string. Just can't seem to get the pattern correct. Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks

The current filter:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
#
# Bans any scanning with the tool sqlmap.
#

[Definition]
# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  Regexp to match the use of sqlmap.
# Values:  TEXT
#
failregex = <HOST> [[] client []] (sqlmap)

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#
ignoreregex =
```

Example log entries:

```
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:08:51 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:08:53 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:08:55 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:08:58 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:08:59 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:01 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:03 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:05 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:06 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:08 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:10 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:11 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:13 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:15 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:16 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:18 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:19 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:21 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:23 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:25 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:27 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:29 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:31 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:33 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:35 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:37 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:39 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:41 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:43 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:45 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:46 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to think about what behavior you want to categorize as an attack. Relying on an `sqlmap` User-Agent is a bad idea, since that is easily changed via a commandline argument. It's likely to protect you against your pen testing service but not against real attackers. This is precisely the situation you want to avoid!

Ideally, you should modify your PHP scripts to log a special message if it can't parse its parameters or if it suspects an injection attack. You can then write a regex to match that log entry and ban attackers at a low retry count. Otherwise, you can just match HTTP status 403 (forbidden). It might be worth looking into other HTTP error codes, too.

Example log line:

```
[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:46 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"
```

Example filter:

```
failregex = []] <HOST> .*HTTP/[0-9.]+" 403
```

This will match all HTTP 403 errors on your site. The `[]]` matches the literal `]` at the end of `[www.domain.com]`, so `HOST` will be `192.168.2.12` in your examples.

You can use `fail2ban-regex` on the commandline to further develop that regular expressions to suit your needs:

```
fail2ban-regex '[www.domain.com] 192.168.2.12 - - [19/Mar/2014:05:09:35 -0600] - "POST /lost_password.php HTTP/1.1" 403 317 "-" "sqlmap/1.0-dev (http://sqlmap.org)"' '[]] <HOST> .*HTTP/[0-9.]+" 403'
```